# What's meaning of ac_cv_file flags in python cross-compile

Tags: python, cross-compiling

there

I tried python cross-compile and it was done.
I just followed how to build tip but I got a question.

When I executed `configure` file, I assigned `ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no`, `ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no` flags. But I don't know the meaning of them.

So I searched about them in google, python homepage, `configure` file's help message and code and so on. Although that, I found out only how to build, not description.

Thus, anyone else could tell me that meaning? or reference?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, `ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx` and `ac_cv_file__dev_ptc` correspond with the device files `/dev/ptmx` and `/dev/ptc` on the target system. [The former apparently represents a pseudoterminal](https://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx). As for the latter, I wasn't able to find any relevant documentation.

As far as I understand, `ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx` and `ac_cv_file__dev_ptc` should be set to `yes` if the corresponding device file is going to be present on the target system and to `no` otherwise.